# Random select after filter in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, random, tags

I'm writing code that, upon given some tags from a video, returns other videos that have similar tags.  It works, but I'm trying to randomise the results.. so I searched and found out that `ORDER BY RAND()` will be quite slow.

After some time, I found [this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)—so I tried to adjust it to my code; here's my attempt at returning a random video:

```
SELECT r1.id, name, site, siteid
FROM   video AS r1 JOIN (
         SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM video)) AS id
       ) AS r2
WHERE  r1.id >= r2.id
LIMIT  4
```

And here's my code to find videos with similar tags:

```
SELECT   v.name, v.site, v.siteid, v.id
FROM     video v
    JOIN video_tag vt ON vt.id_video = v.id
WHERE    vt.id_tag IN ('1','2')
GROUP BY v.id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT vt.id_tag) = 2
```

However, when I try to put them together so I can get 4 random videos with similar tags I just get syntax errors with everything I try.

Any suggestions on how to put them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method chooses 4 *after* figuring out which videos have the same tags:

```
SELECT v.name, v.site, v.siteid, v.id
FROM video v JOIN
     video_tag vt
     ON vt.id_video = v.id
WHERE vt.id_tag IN ('1','2')
GROUP BY v.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT vt.id_tag) = 2
order by rand()
limit 4;
```

You are already grouping by video id, so the additional sort should not drastically affect performance.

Comment: And what if the select returns houndreds of videos? Will still not affect performance?